# Is it ok to generate a random string and using it as an ID on a relational database

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using MYSQL for storing data about my products, I've read on the internet using an auto-incremental number as Primary Key is a really bad idea because anyone could just iterate all through my service and stole my data. For practical proposes it is really handy, now I'm trying to find a better solution,

So far i've created a function in Python that returns a random string of length n from a fixed number of characters to choose from. Now I know it is possible the generated ID was already generated before and stored in DB and the probability that happens is really low at beginning but it will increment with the time, at a point where say half of the IDS are already taken so the probability to fail on creating a new record on DB will fail will be of 50%.

Is it ok to work with IDS this way? or is there any better solution?, how many characters should I use at least to avoid this problem?.

I know UUID exists but I don't think is very userFriendly

Comment: Do the products have an identifier; a serial number? Do the transactions with those products have an ID number (i.e. receipt, generated from a POS, etc)?

Comment: Whom are you trying to be friends with? I have used UUIDs as primary keys, but that's me.

Comment: You're confusing data storage and retrieval with data display. There's no harm at all in have an AI Primary Key. Just don't let that be the thing that users search against.

Comment: No random strings will ever be user friendly, unless those are short and can be reused, like an airline booking code.

Comment: *because anyone could just iterate all through my service and stole my data.* Why this "anyone" have access to your data?

Comment: @Akina I forgot to mention, this program is a Web Application, so I have an end point for retrieving data. The problem is any automated script could just get all the data.

Comment: @Strawberry what would be the way to go then?

Comment: It's too big a question to answer in a comment. Anyway, I doubt that I'm qualified to provide an authoritative answer. But, as a start... Separate the information that MySQL uses internally to relate one bit of information to another from the information that humans use to access the data - and carefully control who has access to what. If you're working with truly sensitive data, consider an RDBMS with stronger support for encryption.